# Adjusting the figure caption

Tags: captions

When leaving the caption empty, I get something like "Figure 11-". How do I remove all the dashes "-" from empty captions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}  % continuous figure number
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
{


\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (3,9);
\coordinate (B) at (2,6);
\draw (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I guess the babel package adds "-" instead of ":"

Comment: Just load the `caption` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the caption package and add this to the preamble:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.},labelsep=space}
```

Comment: Does it interfere with the float package?

Comment: Just like Bernhard has commented above: `\usepackage{caption}` is sufficient to solve this problem. No need for the `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` line.

Comment: @Any The `caption` package is compatible to the `float` package.